# How do I change an active button's appearance to look like it has an arrow pointing

Tags: html, css

So I want to create a button that looks like this when it's active (you can see that it has a little arrow pointing to the right)

[image]

Currently I have something like that, it stays blue after clicked, text turns white and all that. I used `.addClass` for that, but I have no idea if I should use it again to glue on a triangle onto my button, there has to be a better way right?
While I'm at it, how can I make the shadow/sidebar?
Please, experienced people, give this beginner some enlightenment

Comment: add your code here

Comment: Add your css style for that button here

Comment: Usually arrows like that are [pseudo element](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=pseudo+element). Create a pseudo element that resemble an arrow, apply `display:none` when not active, then make it visible when it's active.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rbGJLe
here's what I have so far. I gotta make it the exact same style  assignment for a front end intern/me)
I have to 1. Make it responsive
2.Make those buttons the same shape (Think i can manage that)
3. whenever I click one of those, it has to show the buttons belonging in that category on the right
4. make that shadow card thingy of the side bar
5. make a flowing "news" like stream on bottom right
6.after that I'll have to connect it to a database and get info, show it on the screen, i dunno, getting a bit overwhelmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check following working example.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').find('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li a {
  padding: 10px;
  background: teal;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active::after {
  content: " ";
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid teal;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a class="btn active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="btn">News</a></li>
  <li><a class="btn">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a class="btn">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

add below css for

```css
.active {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.active:after {
  content: "";
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid black;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="active"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```css
.active {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #0092ff;
}

.active:after {
  content: "";
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #0092ff;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 200px;
  transform: translateY(75%);
}

.active:hover:after {
  content: "";
  border-left: 0px solid #0092ff;
  transition: border-left 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="active"></div>
```

Comment: this works, I just have to have my buttons the same size, so it doesn't keep flowing out on the single sentence buttons.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `position:relative` to the selector `ul li`.

after that, you can use the following code below to add content through the pseudo element `after` of the active link.

change the size of the borders, as well as positions for top and right to suit your needs.

```
ul li.active:after {
  content: "";

  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;

  border-left: 20px solid #0092ff;
  position:absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right:-15px;

}
```